# Java Text Reader

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures, text

I want to make a program that read the inputed text and parse every word and store it in a data structure, so i can later have some statistics about that (frequency of words, most common word etc).

I need guidance about two things:

**a.** best approach for my "parse function", which will divide the text in terms

**b.** best approach for data structure choice, in what concerns complexity, access times and best suitable for the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the other stats you need, it sounds like you want to use a `Map<String, Integer>`. Then for each key (the word you read in) you can store how many times you read it in. The rest sounds like homework...

Answer (score 3):

> a) best approach for my "parse function"

Use a [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) it has nice functions for [`next`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) (word) etc.

> b) best approach for datastruture choice

A map from word to a statistics object: `Map<String, WordStatistics>`.

Comment: String tokenizers work pretty well too.  Pretty sure you can just state what you want to tokenize on which may make things even easier.

Comment: @csaunders I think Scanner is even simpler, and it has a [`next(Pattern pattern)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.util.regex.Pattern)) method also.